# Global Constant Declarations

Tags: swift

I am trying to use global constants in a Swift Cocoa application in Xcode. My question is, where to I write the declarations? What kind of file do I use?

Comment: Just create an empty swift file and declare your global constants there.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new file called `Global.swift` and define a struct with static members being the constants you need to avoid polluting the namespace:

```
// Global.swift
private struct MyConstants {
    static let c1 = 1
    static let c2 = 2
}
```

`private` means the struct is local to the current module. When you need to refer to the constants:

```
let x = MyConstants.c1
```